# Wordpress website doesn't work with new hoster (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_magic_quotes())

Tags: php, wordpress

I have changed web hosting provider and moved all files with ftp as well as exported/imported the database and adjusted wp-config.

Old web host only supported php version 7 and the new one supports version 8+.
Is there any way to get the website working again? Thanks a lot

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_magic_quotes() in /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-settings.php:333 Stack trace: #0 /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-config.php(115): require_once() #1 /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/.sites/62...') #2 /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/home/.sites/62...') #3 /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/.sites/62...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/.sites/62/site6733267/web/wp-settings.php on line 333
```

i saw that the function wp_magic_quotes() doesn't work anymore with php version 8.

Comment: For best results, migrate your site from one host to another using a migration plugin. I like Duplicator, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your comment saying wp_magic_quotes doesn't work with PHP8.
You could do this temporarily:

```
function wp_magic_quotes() {
  return true;
}
```

You might need to edit your WP version to one that is compatible with PHP8, it looks like some functions were deprecated / removed with PHP8. Or, go back to PHP7 on your new host somehow?